# Calling a Method from Another Class With No Objects

Tags: java, class, object, methods, call

I am reading numbers in from an array and then use my BubbleSort class to sort the numbers in the array. I am struggling to get my call to the BubbleSort class to work.

---

```
  //Attempted call from the main class to the BubbleSort method in the BubbleSort class

        System.out.println(this.BubbleSort.BubbleSort());
```

---

//BubbleSort Class

package main;

public class BubbleSort {

```
private static void BubbleSort(int[] num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        for (int x = 1; x < num.length - i; x++) {
            if (num[x - 1] > num[x]) {
                int temp = num[x - 1];
                num[x - 1] = num[x];
                num[x] = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for calling a `static` method is `ClassName.methodName(args)`.  Try:

```
int[] numbers = new int[10];  // Could be different size
// Populate it somehow.
BubbleSort.BubbleSort(numbers);
```

Your code used `this` which is a reference to the current object, whose class probably doesn't have a `BubbleSort` member.

Also, currently, your method is `private`, so it can't be called by anything outside that class.  Make it `public` instead.

Additionally, normal Java conventions for naming methods state that the first letter should be lowercase, i.e. the method `bubbleSort` for the class `BubbleSort`.

Comment: I continually receive the same error message as before though, telling me that a non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context and that the variable BubbleSort cannot be found. Thanks.

Comment: The method BubbleSort would be the constructor anyway.  And regardless of naming conventions or language definitions, having a method name be the same as a class name is just asking for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

`BubbleSort` is declared to have an argument of type `int[]` and has access modifier `private`. You need to declare it with access modifier `public` and pass an `int[]` to it as an argument. Create an `int[] array = new int[10]`, add some data using a `for` loop and call `BubbleSort(array)`.

In java code convention, Class name should start with capital letter, function name should not. Please check out the linked page: [**Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Answer (score 0):

So, as a combination of the other two answers plus pointing out another problem you have...

First, the syntax for calling `static` methods is `ClassName.methodName()`, so in this case, you'll want:

```
BubbleSort.BubbleSort(arguments);
```

Second, your `BubbleSort()` method takes an argument, an `int[]`.  You'll need to pass that in.

Third, your `BubbleSort()` method is declared as `private`, which means it can only be called from within the `BubbleSort` class.  If you intend to call this method from outside the `BubbleSort` class, you'll need to make the method `public`.

And finally, `BubbleSort()` has a `void` return.   `System.out.println(BubbleSort.BubbleSort(intArray))` really doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  It will call the method (when you fix all your other problems) and assuming the method is correct, do a bubble sort.  And it will print a line... but the line will be blank.  So if you're intending to print something, you'll need to change the return type to `String` and return the string you want to print.  Otherwise, it makes more sense to just not put it within a `System.out.println()`.

Also... please follow standard naming conventions.  Method names should start with a lowercase letter, and probably shouldn't be the same name as the class in which they're contained (particularly in `Java` where that is going to be confused as a constructor.